# Python -- Multiple Classes and Functions

Tags: python, class

My objective is to create a python code that uses multiple classes and functions that creates a sort of index of different vehicle types and individual attributes for each vehicle. This is what I have so far, but I'm having a tough time with the inventory part where it actually displays all of the vehicles as well as the their attributes. Any advice or help?

`class Vehicle:`

```
def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price):
    self.__make = make
    self.__model = model
    self.__year = year
    self.__mileage = mileage
    self.__price = price

def iMake(self, make):
    self.__make = make

def iModel(self, model):
    self.__model = model

def iYear(self, year):
    self.__year = year

def iMileage(self, mileage):
    self.__mileage = mileage

def iPrice(self, price):
    self.__price = price

def getMake(self):
    return self.__make

def getModel(self):
    return self.__model

def getYear(self):
    return self.__year

def getMileage(self):
    return self.__mileage

def getPrice(self):
    return self.__price
```

`class Car(Vehicle):`

```
#number of doors
def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors):
    Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
    self.__doors = doors
def iDoors(self, doors):   
    self.__doors = doors
def gDoors(self):
    return self.__doors
```

`class Truck(Vehicle):`

```
#drive type (2 or 4 wheel drive)
def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, drive):
    Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
    self.__drive = drive
def iDrive(self, drive):   
    self.__drive = drive
def gDrive(self):
    return self.__drive
```

`class SUV(Vehicle):`

```
#passanger capacity
def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, passengers):
    Vehicle.__init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, passengers)
def capacity(self, passengers):
    self.__passengers = passengers
def gCapacity(self):
    return self.__passengers
```

`class Inventory:`

```
def __init__(self, list1 = []):
    self.list1 = list1[:]
def addVehicle(self, vehicle):
    self.list1.append(vehicle)
def display(self):
    print("The inventory count is ", len(self.list1))
    for vehicle in self.list1:
        vehicle.display()
```

`def main():`

```
inventory = Inventory()
classType = input('Is the vehicle a car, truck, or suv?  ')
if classType == 'car':
    make = input('Please enter the make of the car: ')
    model = input('Please enter the model of the car: ') 
    year = input('Please enter the year of the car: ')
    mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the car: ')
    price = input('Please enter the price of the car: ')
    doors = input('Please enter the amount of doors on the car: ')
    car = Car(make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
    print('Make: ', car.gMake())
    print('Model: ', car.gModel())
    print('Year: ', car.gYear())
    print('Mileage: ', car.gMileage())
    print('Price: ', car.gPrice())
    print('Number of doors: ', car.gDoors())
    print()
elif classType == 'truck':
    make = input('Please enter the make of the truck: ')
    model = input('Please enter the model of the truck: ') 
    year = input('Please enter the year of the truck: ')
    mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the truck: ')
    price = input('Please enter the price of the truck: ')
    drive = input('Please enter 2 wheel or 4 wheel drive for the truck: ')
    truck = Truck(make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
    print('Make: ', truck.gMake())
    print('Model: ', truck.gModel())
    print('Year: ', truck.gYear())
    print('Mileage: ', truck.gMileage())
    print('Price: ', truck.gPrice())
    print('Type of drive: ', truck.gDrive())
    print()
elif classType == 'suv':
    make = input('Please enter the make of the suv: ')
    model = input('Please enter the model of the suv: ') 
    year = input('Please enter the year of the suv: ')
    mileage = input('Please enter the mileage of the suv: ')
    price = input('Please enter the price of the suv: ')
    passengers = input('Please enter the capacity of the suv: ')
    suv = SUV(make, model, year, mileage, price, drive)
    print('Make: ', suv.gMake())
    print('Model: ', suv.gModel())
    print('Year: ', suv.gYear())
    print('Mileage: ', suv.gMileage())
    print('Price: ', suv.gPrice())
    print('Number of passengers: ', suv.gCapacity())
    print()
cont = input('Would you like to add another vehicle?  y/n  ')
if cont == 'y':
    main()
elif cont == 'n':
    inventory.display()
```

Comment: `def __init__(self, list1 = [])`: Beware of using mutable default arguments. Those are evaluated at compile time and not at run time, which might lead to a behaviour that may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

Comment: I've made some significant changes and i know i'm damn close. Any more tips?

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of problems with what you've written for `Inventory`.

First, you've forgotten the `self` arguments in most of your methods. This will lead to a `TypeError` when trying to call them. You have this problem in *many* of your classes, not just `Inventory`.

Second, you wrote `Display` instead of `display`—these aren't the same name, so when you try to call `display` will you get an `AttributeError`.

Third, your default argument `list1 = []` means that every default-constructed `Inventory` will *share* a list, instead of each having its own list. You almost certainly don't want that—unless you intended to copy the list at construction time (to make it *impossible* for any two `Inventory` objects to share a list). Just in case that *is* what you wanted, I'll show how to do it.

Now, an `Inventory` is just a wrapper around a list of `Vehicle`s, right? So:

```
class Inventory:
    def __init__(self, list1=[]):
        self.list1 = list1[:]
    def addVehicle(self, vehicle):
        self.list1.append(vehicle)
    def display(self):
        print("Inventory count:", len(self.list1))
        for vehicle in self.list1:
            vehicle.display()
```

---

Meanwhile, your various `Vehicle` subclasses are *overriding* the base class `display` method, which means they either have to explicitly *call* the base method, via `super`, or have to replace everything it would have done. So, for example, in `Car`:

```
def display(self):
    super(Car, self).display()
    print("Number of doors: ", self.doors)
```

---

Another problem is that some of your subclasses have methods and attributes with the same name, like this:

```
def doors(self, doors):   
    self.doors = doors
```

Once you call that, you can never call the `doors` method again, because it's now been hidden by the number of doors. (Plus, if you call `display` *before* calling `doors`, it's going to display the `doors` method object as the number of doors, which is pretty ugly.)

In fact, you probably don't want "setter" methods like this. Set values in the constructor, and if you want the user to change the values after construction, they can just change the attributes directly. So, for example:

```
class Car(vehicle):
    def __init__(self, make, model, year, mileage, price, doors=4):
        super(Car, self).__init__(make, model, year, mileage, price)
        self.doors = doors
    def display(self):
        # etc.
```

And then:

```
car = Car(make, model, year, mileage, price, doors)
```

---

If you want to remember all these vehicles, you have to tell Python to remember them. You can `append`each one to a list as you create it, or you can just `addVehicle` them all to an `Inventory` in the first place. Like this:

```
elif classType == 'truck':
    make = raw_input('Please enter the make of the truck: ')
    # etc.
    truck.display()
    inventory.addVehicle(truck)
```

Of course you will have to have done `inventory = Inventory()` beforehand.

---

Meanwhile, from your use of `raw_input`, this is clearly Python 2. That means you're creating old-style classes. Never do that. Always inherit your base classes from `object`.

---

Also, in Python 2, `print("a", 2)` won't print `a 2`, it'll print `('a', 2)`, which probably isn't what you want. In this case, you can get Python 3 behavior by using `from __future__ import print_function` at the very top of your script. If you don't do that, you will want to change your print statements to not have the parentheses.

Or, better, use string formatting so you only have a single argument to print, like `print("Price: {}".format(self.price))`, which will do the exact same thing in both Python 2 and Python 3.

---

Finally, if you want to keep looping over the body of `main` repeatedly, you're much better off with a `while` loop than by recursively calling `main()` from itself.

But in fact, you'd probably be happier factoring out the whole body into a separate `oneVehicle` function, which just returns whatever vehicle the user created. (Note that this can be `None`, because you allow them to type nonsense without an error. Which is fine, as long as you deal with it.) Then `main` can look like this:

```
def main():
    inventory = Inventory()
    while True:
        vehicle = oneVehicle()
        if vehicle:
            inventory.addVehicle(vehicle)
        cont = raw_input('Would you like to add another vehicle?  y/n  ')
        if cont != 'y':
            break
    inventory.display()
```